# Looping range based on condition

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I want to say something like:

```
if switch == True:
    for i in range(5):
        # stuff()
else:
    for i in range(10):
        # stuff()
```

Is there a more Pythonic way for this?

Comment: If the entire body of the loop is just a trivial function call `stuff()`, you're really not repeating yourself here in any significant way. And if the body of the loop is long and complicated… well, you can always factor it out into a function. So, while there may be (well, are…) briefer or more readable solutions, this one isn't that bad in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combine it in one with a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
for i in range(5 if switch else 10):
    # do something with i
```

You don't need to test for `== True` here; `if` *already* does this for you.

A little more readable would be to separate out the end value into a variable:

```
end = 5 if switch else 10
for i in range(end):
    # do something with i
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an inline short form of `if/else`:

```
for i in range(5 if switch else 10):
    # stuff()
```